# Custom view for listView - font

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts, android-listview

I have problem with setting up own font for my ListView, I don't know how to use own Adapter class and what xml do I need (besides that one in which I put ListView). I'm hoping (in ListView) just for centered text with own font.
Thats my Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private String[]       objects; // no objects just String array
private final Context   context;

public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] objects) {
    this.context = context;
    this.objects = objects;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return objects[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Object obj = objects[position];

    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setText(obj.toString());
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/kolejRogFont.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(tf);

    return tv;
}
}
```

and it's calling in Lista.java

```
ListView lv = new ListView(this);
    lv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, listview_array));
```

Codes are from another topic on StackOverFlow.

1. I get an error on line (undefined method):

   Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/kolejRogFont.ttf");

2.Nothings appear on the screen. Should I make a XML for ListView Layout? What should it contain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change MyAdapter  Code as:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Typeface tf;
private String[]       objects; // no objects just String array
private final Context   context;

public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] objects) {
    this.context = context;
    this.objects = objects;
    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/kolejRogFont.ttf");
}
////Your code ...

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Object obj = objects[position];

    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setText(obj.toString());
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
    return tv;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It working, also after changing in Lista.java "ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaMenu);" just sub-question, how can I add margins to it? I made already "tv.setTextSize(40); tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);"

Answer (score 1):

`getAssets()` is from `Context`, so it is undefined to your adapter. Try using this:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/kolejRogFont.ttf");
```

Edit: As a side note, I would move that line to the constructor and set `tf` as a class variable. There's really no need to load the font every time it gets a view.

Answer (score 0):

for your answer about set margin to your list view, you should set margin in your list_view_items.zml. e.g. set margin or padding in your Linear layout.

Comment: This should be a comment, not not an answer.